# How can I make Vuetify mobile responsive navigation bar and linked drawer have NESTED menus?

Tags: vue.js, nested, navigation-drawer, vuetify.js

I am making a navbar component through the Vue framework using Vuetify. I would like to make the products item have a drop down into two links.

This is the template html and script code (I have some additional custom CSS for color and such that I am not adding here):

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-toolbar id="navbar" dense elevation=1 dark >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="hidden-md-and-up" @click="sidebar = !sidebar"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-navigation-drawer v-model="sidebar" app hide-overlay temporary>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in menuItems" exact :key="i" :to="item.path">{{item.title}}</v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>

      <v-toolbar-items d-flex>
        <v-btn href="#" id="logo" flat depressed text>Company Name</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn text v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.title">
          <router-link :to="item.path">{{item.title}}</router-link>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
  <script>
   export default {
    data: function() {
           return {
      sidebar: false,
      menuItems: [
        { path: "/product", name: "product", title: "Product" },
        { path: "/us", name: "us", title: "Us" },
        { path: "resources", name: "resources", title: "Resources" },
        { path: "/portal", name: "login", title: "Login" }
      ]
    };
  }
};

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

How about app-bar? 
v-menu tag support drop down
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#dense